# how to read 2 txt files and write the result in a third file using python

Tags: python

I have 3 files with the following content:

today.txt

**570**

yesterday.txt

**500**

now.txt

**0**

Basically, i need to read the first 2 files and write the result in the third file:

today.txt - yesterday.txt = now.txt (570 - 500 = 70)

Comment: OK. What have you tried in order to solve this? Please show your code and explain what difficulties you are having

Comment: Does the file have only one number ?

Comment: thank you idjaw for for the question, but its solved w/ the Anoop Toffy answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open file for reading, read the integer, do the math, write back the results

```
fpToday = open("today.txt", "r")
fpYesterday = open("yesterday.txt","r")
fpNow = open("now.txt","w")
numToday = fpToday.read().rstrip('\n')
numYesterday =fpYesterday.read().rstrip('\n')
numNow = int(numToday) - int(numYesterday)
fpNow.write(str(numNow))
fpToday.close()
fpYesterday.close()
fpNow.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

`

```
with open("today.txt", "r") as today:
    with open("yesterday.txt", "r") as yesterday:
        with open("now.txt", "a") as now:
            today = today.read()
            yesterday = yesterday.read()
            result = int(today) - int(yesterday)
            now.write(str(result))
            # TO SEE 'now' FILE
            with open("now.txt", "r") as now:
                print("\n".join(now))
```

`

Comment: thank you, but this dont worked here, i got "IdentationError: unexpected unident" but another answer solved this, so thank you anyway

Comment: ok its good to hear your answer was fixed